# Accessing local .swf file from the web (html page)

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer, local

Our company uses learning management system to teach employees. We have very slow internet connection in some offices. The courses that have video content do not run at all.

Our courses mainly consist of html page that launches .swf-file that launches a bunch of video files.

We thought about copying .swf-file and all the videos to a network drive in every office. In that case, user would start an .html page > .html page would ask him to show a path to a .swf-file > browser would play all that.

Of cause our method would not work, since local (or network in our case) files cannot be accessed and played from the web.

We use Internet Explorers only. Would it be possible to build an IE extension to make it work? Could you show me an example or give an advice on how to do it?

Important: .sfw-file should work in browser as it should be able to connect to LMS to save progress and publish scores.

Comment: for security reason remote html cannot load local resources, including swf of course. so in your case, the best way is to deploy an intranet within those offices. read here on Adobe help:http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html

Comment: This link is for AIR I believe. It is difficult to implement and All AIR applications have to be deployed in every local machines. But though it is good learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one trick you can adapt to.

Since you are ready to put all your tutorial videos **in a network drive per an office of you**, It will be good to put them in a running `apache httpd` instance. (Any lightweight http server, for that matter).

That way, you can access them in html pages, speed of the buffering would be just like local file system. You can also be in touch with your LMS about the  progress and do your stats.

Please let us know if this helped finally.

Comment: If your company already has a web server, you can just add a virtual folder and "simulate" the web behaviour. If not, you may talk to IT about installing Apache or IIS on the machine where the files will reside. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

upload your swf file to:  http://swf-to-exe.com/

and convert it to exe and run..

Answer (score 1):

On the machine you want to run your app you can go to this URL:
 
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html 
(this is the setting panel for the Flash player, it's not an image)
and add the SWF path to the 'trusted locations'.

Comment: I doubt that it would work. AFAIK, trusted location is for local access only.

Comment: What I mean, is `trusted location` allows local -> local access, but I need 'web' -> 'local'

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking if you can try editting hosts file to redirect video request from source server to local network.

or

if you LMS is based on HTML, it is quite easy to write a JavaScript plug-in to replace all video link.